# Rails nested resource creation on separate pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
resources :books do 
    resources :chapters
end
```

Let's assume I have the above properly nested resources. I want to create a page where I create parent book resources and another page to create the chapters resources. When creating chapters, I want users to be able to select parent books they created.

Right now I have...

```
protected
def find_book
    @book = Book.find(params[:book_id])
end
```

...in the chapter controller but I believe this only works when there is already a book id present in the URL. So to create a new chapter I would have to visit "rootpath/book/book_id/chapter/new" when I want to be able to create chapters on a separate page.

Although I'm really not sure how to approach the problem, right now my plan is to put an association(?) form on the chapter creation page that links the nested resources.

The problem is, I'm really new to web development and I'm not sure if I'm approaching this right at all. How would I put a form that sends :book_id to the chapter controller? Would this method work at all? Are there more efficient ways to go at it?

I realize my questions might be a little vague but **Any help** would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dull answer is: your proposal does not make sense with only the nested route.

The nested route implies that upon accessing the `chapters#new` action, you already know exactly which book that should contain the chapter.

But on the bright side: you can use both nested and non-nested routes at the same time.

If you want to keep the nested route, but also provide a `new` and `create` actions that lets the user choose the desired Book for the chapter, you can add a non-nested route for Chapter creation.

For example:

```
resources :books do
  resources :chapters
end
resources :chapters
```

Note that your controllers may need to be rewritten a bit to accomodate the dual routes.

If you want, you could create both resources in the same page. Look up `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to do that. It's really easy, once you get the hang of it.